# Paging images dynamically from database by using repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, paging

i have some images .now it is displaying 3 images in a row and there are many columns it means there are 30 or more images displaying in page as 3 in a row.so i want to make it dynamically loaded from database .so am going to use repeater but i need to 12 images in a page as 3*4 and others in next page.like wise i want to implement paging of images that loading from database.so please help me to solve this problem ,i dint know about is there any telerik or other types of controls to make this task easy...

Comment: i suggest instead of repeater you use datalist control. https://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/datalist.aspx

Comment: we can use data list but how i show images that loading dynamically from database in page wise view.

Comment: i assume the images is not save in your database? only the image path correct? then you just neet to bind it and let the datalist do the pagination for you.

Comment: am saving the images in database.my problem is when i load all images to pages there are many images in same page .so i want to show images in different pages .i want to see images by clicking page number 1,2,3,4.....so this will create according to how many pictures there in data base.

Comment: explore the datalist object, it had the automatic pagination process.